# Libgdx remove and add image from cells

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have this table:

```
table.add(image1).size(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight());
table.add().size(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight()).row();
table.add().size(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight());
table.add().size(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight());
```

I want, when I clicked on empty cell, image deleted from cell and add to the clicked cell. For example when I clicked on third cell, remove image1 from first cell and add it to the third cell. How can do it?

**Update 2:**

I wrote this code but when I click on cell1, image1 is not added on table and added on right screen and click on cell0 don't work.

```
Group group = new Group();
    group.addActor(image1);
    group.addActor(image2);
    group.addActor(image3);
    root.add(group).size(16, 16);
    root.add(image4).size(image4.getWidth(), image3.getHeight()).row();
    root.add(image5).size(image5.getWidth(), image4.getHeight());
    root.add(image6).size(image6.getWidth(), image5.getHeight());

    stage.addActor(root);
    stage.setDebugAll(true);

    root.getChildren().get(1).addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            root.getCells().get(1).clearActor();
            root.getCells().get(0).clearActor();
            root.getCells().get(0).setActor(image1);
            group.clear();
            group.addActor(image4);
            group.addActor(image2);
            group.addActor(image3);
            root.getCells().get(1).setActor(group);
            return true;
        }
    });

    root.getChildren().get(0).addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            root.getCells().get(0).clearActor();
            root.getCells().get(1).clearActor();
            root.getCells().get(1).setActor(image4);
            group.clear();
            group.addActor(image1);
            group.addActor(image2);
            group.addActor(image3);
            root.getCells().get(0).setActor(group);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would set a listener for each table cell that would clear the cell that has 'image1' and then assign the image in the cell that was clicked. Something like:

```
table.getChildren().get(0).addListener(new ClickListener(  // .get(0-3)
   Cell<Table> cell = table.getCell(image1);
   cell.clearActor();
   table.getCells().get(0).setActor(image1);               // .get(0-3)
));
```

[Read libgdx's table api page](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Table.html).